# I can t get String from my databasehandler Java

Tags: java, arrays, database

- Hi I am trying to get String from my databasehandler. I don t get any error just instead of string I get id s like that. *

com.example.drinkingtime.Treburi.NumeBazaDeDate@752fc40

Please any help? I am beginner in programming

```
 public void test(){
            ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<>();
            a.add("ana are mere");
            a.add("ana are mere");
            a.add("ana are mere");
                DataBaseHandler db=new DataBaseHandler(this);
                String y=db.getNume(2).toString();
                String z=a.get(0).replace("mere",y);
                intrebari.setText(z);
                Log.d("hi", "HI "+y);
       }
```

and here it s databasehandler

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final Context context;

    public DataBaseHandler(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, Util.DATABASE_NAME, null, Util.DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Util.TABLE_NAME + "("
                + Util.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Util.KEY_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_NAME);

        //create a table again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addName(NumeBazaDeDate numeBazaDeDate) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Util.KEY_NAME, numeBazaDeDate.getNume());

        db.insert(Util.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    public NumeBazaDeDate getNume(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(Util.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{Util.KEY_ID, Util.KEY_NAME},
                Util.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        NumeBazaDeDate numeBazaDeDate = new NumeBazaDeDate();
        numeBazaDeDate.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        numeBazaDeDate.setNume(cursor.getString(1));

        return numeBazaDeDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `String y=db.getNume(2).getNume();`

Comment: it work thanks guys. You are awesome. Yes it s logic I get a full object and after i need to get just name yess. Thanksss

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```java
String y=db.getNume(2).toString();
```

You convert your object to String calling toString method. By default this method returns full class name and object address joined with @.

You should override the method, so that it would return what you want. Field values, joined with , for example.

Say, if NumeBazaDeDate has **name** field and you want **y** variable to contain **name** form db, here's how **toString** method should look like

```java
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: and how should I do that I used ctrl+o to get it but what I should wrote there?